# When I click on export this error occurs in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

> Warning in ./../../php/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_fonts.php#1671
>    chr() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given
>
> Backtrace
>
> tcpdf_fonts.php#1671: chr(string '')
>   tcpdf_fonts.php#1803: TCPDF_FONTS::unichr(
>   string '',
>   boolean true,
>   )
>   tcpdf_fonts.php#2095: TCPDF_FONTS::UTF8ArrSubString(
>   array,
>   integer 0,
>   integer 1,
>   boolean true,
>   )
>   tcpdf.php#1960: TCPDF_FONTS::utf8Bidi(
>   array,
>   string '',
>   boolean false,
>   boolean true,
>   NULL,
>   )
>   ./libraries/classes/Pdf.php#50: TCPDF->__construct(
>   string 'L',
>   string 'pt',
>   string 'A3',
>   boolean true,
>   string 'UTF-8',
>   boolean false,
>   boolean false,
>   )
>   ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Export/Helpers/Pdf.php#58: PhpMyAdmin\Pdf->__construct(
>   string 'L',
>   string 'pt',
>   string 'A3',
>   boolean true,
>   string 'UTF-8',
>   boolean false,
>   boolean false,
>   )
>   ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Export/ExportPdf.php#70: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\Helpers\Pdf->__construct(
>   string 'L',
>   string 'pt',
>   string 'A3',
>   )
>   ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Export/ExportPdf.php#55: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportPdf->initSpecificVariables()[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcS1E.png)
>   ./libraries/classes/Plugins.php#99: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportPdf->__construct()
>   ./libraries/classes/Display/Export.php#677: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins::getPlugins(
>   string 'export',
>   string 'libraries/classes/Plugins/Export/',
>   array,
>   )
>   ./db_export.php#147: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Export->getDisplay(
>   string 'database',
>   string 'wordpress',
>   string '',
>   string '',
>   integer 14,
>   integer 0,
>   string 'TablesStructureDataSelect all wp_commentmetawp_commentswp_linkswp_optionswp_postmetawp_postswp_termmetawp_termswp_term_relationshipswp_term_taxonomywp_usermetawp_userswp_yoast_seo_linkswp_yoast_seo_meta ',
>   )

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Run this command:

```
sudo nano +1671 /usr/share/php/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_fonts.php
```

Add this condition `is_numeric($c)` in the public method body, so change:

```
public static function unichr($c, $unicode=true) {
    if (!$unicode) {
        return chr($c);
    } elseif ($c <= 0x7F) {
        // one byte
        return chr($c);
    } elseif ($c <= 0x7FF) {
        // two bytes
        return chr(0xC0 | $c >> 6).chr(0x80 | $c & 0x3F);
    } elseif ($c <= 0xFFFF) {
        // three bytes
        return chr(0xE0 | $c >> 12).chr(0x80 | $c >> 6 & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | $c & 0x3F);
    } elseif ($c <= 0x10FFFF) {
        // four bytes
        return chr(0xF0 | $c >> 18).chr(0x80 | $c >> 12 & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | $c >> 6 & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | $c & 0x3F);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

To

```
public static function unichr($c, $unicode=true) {
    if (is_numeric($c)){
        if (!$unicode) {
            return chr($c);
        } elseif ($c <= 0x7F) {
            // one byte
            return chr($c);
        } elseif ($c <= 0x7FF) {
            // two bytes
            return chr(0xC0 | $c >> 6).chr(0x80 | $c & 0x3F);
        } elseif ($c <= 0xFFFF) {
            // three bytes
            return chr(0xE0 | $c >> 12).chr(0x80 | $c >> 6 & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | $c & 0x3F);
        } elseif ($c <= 0x10FFFF) {
            // four bytes
            return chr(0xF0 | $c >> 18).chr(0x80 | $c >> 12 & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | $c >> 6 & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | $c & 0x3F);
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be just a workaround. [Veeru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60825855/455716) seems to be the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue simply I have upgraded the PHPMyAdmin and MYSQL latest version.

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution is to downgrade your PHP version, assuming you are running on PHP 7.4. Alternatively refer to this URL https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/pull/123/commits/34eb0dff48eb0b0d5f38f4cfd92ef6d47aefc8b4

There is a fix for this error with TCPDF